# Last segment of IP Address

Tags: ip, ping

I am writing a pinging utility to check the connectivity. We have an IP range from X.X.X.0 - X.X.X.24

`Ping X.X.X.08` - gives unknown host

`Ping X.X.X.008`- gives unknown host

`Ping X.X.X.8` - gets successful response

How many digits should be there in the last octet?

[image]

---

But when I ping X.X.X.007 or X.X.X.07 or X.X.X.7 works, i get successful response.

Could some shade some light what i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends almost entirely on the implementation of your `ping` but the most likely cause is that the `08` is being treated as an *octal* number because it begins with `0`.

And, since the valid octal digits are limited to `0..7`, it assumes it's *not* a numeric IP address but instead a *name* to be looked up (in DNS, for example).

This octal behavior can be confirmed (under Windows) with the following transcript:

```
C:\Users\Pax> ping 192.168.1.061
Pinging 192.168.1.49 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.61: Destination host unreachable.
:
```

The `061` appears to have been treated as octal from the first line of the output, since `618 (6x8+1) = 4910`. The subsequent lines, though they *claim* to be pinging the `.61` address, are lying. That's because that's my *actual* machine and, if I do it without the leading zero, it works fine:

```
C:\Users\Pax>ping 192.168.1.61
Pinging 192.168.1.61 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.61: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
:
```

If the octal bit contains a non-octal digit, *that's* when it starts complaining about the host itself rather than it just not being reachable (or, worse, pinging the wrong machine):

```
C:\Users\Pax>ping 192.168.1.61
Pinging 192.168.1.61 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.61: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
:

C:\Users\Pax>ping 192.0168.1.61
Ping request could not find host 192.0168.1.61.
    Please check the name and try again.
```

Comment: Got it. Currently i am not prefixing any zero's if it is<10. ping on terminal gives unknown host when prefix zero for 8 and 9. But it makes sense, it might be treating as octal number.

Comment: Make sense. So in code it make sense not to prefix zero when last segment < 10, just to be safe. thanks @paxdiablo

Comment: @jeevjyotsinghchhabda, I would rather suggest it makes sense not to prefix *any* of the segments with zero, not just the last one. For example, `192.168.10.1` and `192.168.010.1` are two totally *different* IP addresses. The latter is the same as `192.168.8.1`.

Comment: Yes @paxdiablo, you're right. In my case, i am generating Ip's for a given Ip range, so i have to take care of only last octect. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it doesn't matter if you have X.X.X.001 or .01 or .1 for the last octet.
See my ping results on 192.168.0.1 and .01 and .001 => they all result to .1
[image: ping results]

Comment: I suspect that's only because decimal 1 and octal 1 are the same thing :-)